# Function field of $\mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-varieties

What is the function field of $\mathbb{P}^1$ when $\mathbb{P}^1$ is viewed as a projective curve? From what I read, I think it should be $k(x)$, but I don't understand how.

Comment: What is your definition of function field? A convenient definition is "fraction field of $A$ for any affine open $\operatorname{Spec}A \subset \mathbb P^1$. So take the affine open $\mathbb A^1$ with coordinate ring $k[x]$, so the fraction field is $k(x)$.

Comment: @TabesBridges I'm studying from Hartshorne where function field is defined as following:If Y is a variety, then the function field K(Y) of Y is as follows:
an element of K(Y) is an equivalence class of pairs (U,f) where U is a
nonempty open subset of Y, f is a regular function on U, and where
we identify two pairs (U,f) and (V,g) iff f = g on $U \cap V$. Can you please tell how to obtain the result for this definition?

Answer (score 5):

The only regular functions on $\mathbb P^1$ are constants, so you have to pass to nontrivial open subsets to get anything interesting. But once you have deleted a single point, you are now looking at $\mathbb A^1$ or a subset thereof, and the ring of regular functions on $\mathbb A^1 \setminus \left\{ a_1,a_2,...,a_n \right\}$ is $k\left[x,\frac{1}{x-a_1}, \frac{1}{x-a_2},...,\frac{1}{x-a_n}\right]$. Now as you vary over all possible finite subsets you get a directed system of rings starting with $k \subset k[x]$ (and the other possible ways to include $k$ into a one variable polynomial ring by deleting a point from $\mathbb P^1$). Taking the colimit over this system you obtain $k(x)$, essentially as a consequence of the universal property of localization.